# SPL Token 2022 initialize_group - "Invalid Instruction"

Tags: solana-program, token-2022, token-extensions

** The code is functional. The issue was with the test framework. See solution **.

I'm trying to create a group mint with token-2022.

I've followed the steps in:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022-test/tests/token_group_initialize.rs

Being an interface, i've used the spl-token-2022 program id with all of the instructions. Have not provided my own implementations.

The instructions in order (full code at the end of the question):

1. create mint account (with enough lamports to cover group pointer)
2. initialise the group pointer extension on the mint created in (1)
3. initialise the mint
4. initialize_group

Instructions 1-3 execute correctly. However at step (4) I'm hit with "Invalid Instruction".

```
[2024-01-07T19:33:59.051326000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]
[2024-01-07T19:33:59.051718000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Error: Invalid instruction
```

Full code:

```
pub fn create_group_mint_combined(
    payer: &Signer,
    group_mint: &Signer,
    authority: &AccountInfo,
    authority_seeds: &[&[u8]],
    max_group_size: u32,
) -> Result {
    let rent = Rent::get()?;
    let mint_space =
        ExtensionType::try_calculate_account_len::(&[ExtensionType::GroupPointer])?;
    let mint_rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(mint_space);
    invoke(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            &payer.key(),
            &group_mint.key(),
            mint_rent_lamports,
            mint_space.try_into().unwrap(),
            &spl_token_2022::ID,
        ),
        &[payer.to_account_info(), group_mint.to_account_info()],
    )?;
    let initialize_extension = spl_token_2022::extension::group_pointer::instruction::initialize(
        &spl_token_2022::ID,
        &group_mint.key(),
        Some(authority.key()),
        Some(group_mint.key()),
    )
    .unwrap();
    invoke_signed(
        &initialize_extension,
        &[
            group_mint.to_account_info(),
            authority.to_account_info(),
            group_mint.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[authority_seeds],
    )?;


    let initialize_ix = initialize_mint2(
        &spl_token_2022::ID,
        &group_mint.key(),
        &authority.key(),
        Some(&authority.key()),
        0,
    )
    .unwrap();
    msg!("Invoke initialise mint2");
    invoke_signed(
        &initialize_ix,
        &[group_mint.to_account_info()],
        &[authority_seeds],
    )?;

    msg!("Initialize group");
    
    invoke_signed(
        &initialize_group(
            &spl_token_2022::ID,
            &group_mint.key(),
            &group_mint.key(),
            &authority.key(),
            // Pubkey::new_unique().into(),
            Some(authority.key()),
            max_group_size,
        ),
        &[
            group_mint.to_account_info(),
            authority.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[authority_seeds],
    )?;
    msg!("Invoked");
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing a little snippet from my test configuration.

The Invalid Instruction error was due to an spl-token-2022 library version mismatch in the framework. The following works to fix it:

```
program.prefer_bpf(false);
program.add_program(
  "spl_token_2022",
  spl_token_2022::id(),
  processor!(Processor::process),
);
```